# What is the cause of frequent nightmares?

Tags: sleep, dreams

Is there a reason why people dream of demons, ghosts, and other scary creatures? More specifically:

**What factors cause frequent nightmares to occur**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nightmares can be defined as [(Pagel, 2000)](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2000/0401/p2037.html):

> ...vivid and terrifying nocturnal episodes in which the dreamer is abruptly awakened from sleep. Typically, the dreamer wakes from REM sleep and is able to describe a detailed, associative, often bizarre dream plot. Usually, the dreamer has difficulty returning to sleep.

Nightmares are common and can be a normal reaction to stress. Frequent occurrence of nightmares, however, may become a disorder when it impairs the sufferer's everyday life and may then be referred to as Nightmare Disorder (formerly Dream Anxiety Disorder) or "repeated nightmares," which is a term defined more specifically as a series of nightmares with a recurring theme (source: [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/conditions/nightmares)).

**[Nightmare disorder](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/914428-overview)** is defined in the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (DSM-5) as:

> [R]epeated awakenings with recollection of terrifying dreams, usually
>   involving threats to survival, safety or physical integrity.

Causes of nightmare disorder, according to [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/guide/nightmares-in-adults#2), [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/conditions/nightmares) and [(Sheaves *et al*., 2015)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4542515/) are:

- Anxiety or stress, for example due to a major life event
- Depression
- Psychosis
- Sleep deprivation
- Illness with a fever
- Medication side effects
- Drug or alcohol withdrawal
- Excessive alcohol consumption
- Sleep apnea, narcolepsy or restless legs syndrome or other sleep disorders
- Eating just before going to bed, which raises the body's metabolism and brain activity

<sub>**References**

**-** [Pagel, *Am Fam Physician* (2000); **61**(7): 2037-42](http://www.aafp.org/afp/2000/0401/p2037.html)

**-** [Sheaves *et al*., *Can J Psychiatry* (2015); **60**(8): 354–61](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4542515/)</sub>